# How to build xerces-j 2.11 with an up-to-date JVM?

Tags: java, ant, build, xerces

I have checked out xerces-j 2.11 from https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xerces/java/tags/Xerces-J_2_11_0. Now I would like to build it, but I get the following errors during comilation:

```
compile:
   [xjavac] Compiling 596 source files to C:\Users\abrieg\workingcopy\xerces-trunk\build\classes
   [xjavac] C:\Users\abrieg\workingcopy\xerces-trunk\build\src\org\apache\html\dom\HTMLFrameElementImpl.java:28: error: HTMLFrameElementImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method getContentDocument() in HTMLFrameElement
   [xjavac] public class HTMLFrameElementImpl
   [xjavac]        ^
   [xjavac] C:\Users\abrieg\workingcopy\xerces-trunk\build\src\org\apache\html\dom\HTMLIFrameElementImpl.java:28: error: HTMLIFrameElementImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method getContentDocument() in HTMLIFrameElement
   [xjavac] public class HTMLIFrameElementImpl
   [xjavac]        ^
   [xjavac] C:\Users\abrieg\workingcopy\xerces-trunk\build\src\org\apache\html\dom\HTMLObjectElementImpl.java:28: error: HTMLObjectElementImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method getContentDocument() in HTMLObjectElement
   [xjavac] public class HTMLObjectElementImpl
   [xjavac]        ^
   [xjavac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
   [xjavac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
   [xjavac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
   [xjavac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
   [xjavac] 3 errors
```

The problem is that the xjavac task does not use the classes from the `/tools/xml-apis.jar` but instead uses `rt.jar` of the jdk.
The compilation is running in the following VM:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

I already used the endorsed libraries override mechanism to put the `xml-apis.jar` of xerces-j 2.11 in the VM, but this didn't work.

The `xjavac` invocation is defined as

```
<xjavac srcdir="${build.src}"
       destdir="${build.dest}"
       source="${javac.source}"
       target="${javac.target}"
       classpath="${build.dir}/classes:${tools.dir}/${jar.apis}:${tools.dir}/${jar.resolver}:${tools.dir}/${jar.serializer}"
       debug="${debug}"
       debuglevel="${debuglevel}"
       deprecation="${deprecation}"
       optimize="${optimize}"
       includeAntRuntime="false"
       includeJavaRuntime="false"
       excludes="org/xml/sax/** 
            javax/xml/**
            org/w3c/dom/*
            org/w3c/dom/bootstrap/**
            org/w3c/dom/events/**
            org/w3c/dom/ls/**
            org/w3c/dom/html/**
            org/w3c/dom/ranges/**
            org/w3c/dom/traversal/**
            org/w3c/dom/views/**
            org/w3c/dom/xpath/**"
       />
```

How can I make sure that `xml-apis.jar` is used for compilation instead of the classes from my JVM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to **prepend** the `xml-apis.jar` to the [bootstrap classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) of the Javac.

```
<xjavac srcdir="${build.src}"
       destdir="${build.dest}"
       source="${javac.source}"
       target="${javac.target}"
       classpath="${build.dir}/classes:${tools.dir}/${jar.apis}:${tools.dir}/${jar.resolver}:${tools.dir}/${jar.serializer}"
       debug="${debug}"
       debuglevel="${debuglevel}"
       deprecation="${deprecation}"
       optimize="${optimize}"
       includeAntRuntime="false"
       includeJavaRuntime="false"
       excludes="org/xml/sax/** 
            javax/xml/**
            org/w3c/dom/*
            org/w3c/dom/bootstrap/**
            org/w3c/dom/events/**
            org/w3c/dom/ls/**
            org/w3c/dom/html/**
            org/w3c/dom/ranges/**
            org/w3c/dom/traversal/**
            org/w3c/dom/views/**
            org/w3c/dom/xpath/**"
       >
       <compilerarg line="-Xbootclasspath/p:${tools.dir}/${jar.apis}"/>
</xjavac>
```

Comment: The documentation of javac says `-Xbootclasspath/p` *Adds a suffix to the bootstrap class path.*. Anyway this works just fine.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker this is clearly an error in the documentation. A bug report has been submitted. If you run `javac -X` you get the right explanation.

Comment: For the record the bug was filed as [JDK-8073401](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8073401)